How do i know if this if this is already a song or not?
Here is the song I came up with for my kid that is like Hush Baby but with different nt lyrics, I wanna know if it's already a song
"Hush baby, don't you cry. Papa's gonna hold you through the night, and if the monsters come out to play, papa's gonna scare them all away. Don't you worry about the night, papa's gonna stay here to hold you tight"

Did you try googling the lyrics you came up with? Either way, I'm not sure this question is on-topic here.

Your lyrics follow the basic structure of “Hush Little Baby”. If you are using the melody from that song, what you are doing is simply writing alternate lyrics to a preexisting song. If you have your own unique melody it is an original song.

You only gave the lyrics, so this is a question about poetry and is not covered here. Fortunately, searching for texts is much easier than searching for melodies.
